# Two self-adjoint operators with the same eigenvalues and eigenfunctions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

How to show two self-adjoint operators (unbounded) on a Hilbert space with the same eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are the same.

Comment: In general, they are not, since the eigenfunctions may or may not form a basis for the Hilbert space.

Comment: suppose they form a basis, can we show they are same? I don't know if how to do that since they may be unbounded…

Comment: Are you assuming that the eigenfunctions have the same eigenvalues, or just that the sets of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are the same?

Comment: same eigenvalue and same eigenspace if have multiplicity more than one.

Comment: @changer: you probably mean that the eigenfunctions form an orthonormal base of the Hilbert space, or the linear span of eigenfunctions is dense.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true. Consider the operators $T,S \colon L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$, given by 
$$ Tx(t) = tx(t), \quad Sx(t) = t^2x(t). $$
Both are self-adjoint, and both have no eigenvalues. But $S \ne T$, as $S1 \ne T1$.